# Get link to google drive file for third party web application

Tags: google-drive-api

I am trying to build a photo sharing web application and using google drive to store the images uploaded to my application.

I have uploaded an image and would like to store the image link in a database which I can then send to my react application.

Python Code:

```py
file_id = '1WgtmLUXjKBTNIsbQBCdR1pCBF1i3k3rw'
meta_data = self.service.files().get(fileId = file_id).execute()
print(meta_data)

{'kind': 'drive#file', 'id': '1WgtmLUXjKBTNIsbQBCdR1pCBF1i3k3rw', 'name': 'nature6.jpg', 'mimeType': 'image/jpeg'}
```

Comment: I cannot understand about your current issue. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about it?

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

You can specify which fields you want to receive when making the call by passing the `fields` argument with a list of fields. Check the `optional query parameters` of the method [get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get)

```py
fileId = '1NSFqFCHv_xsAsyT9jZl7hlAhNxBkIhQl'
fields ='id, name, webViewLink'
result = service.files().get(fileId=fileId, fields=fields).execute()
link = result['webViewLink']
```

In addition, you can also use the `fields` argument when using the [create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create) method, so you don't have to make another extra call to get the link.

### Reference

- [Drive: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get)
- [Drive: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create)